# Correct Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java Regex to read String of the type

```
"{\n  'Step 1.supply.vendor1.quantity':\"80"\,\n
      'Step 2.supply.vendor2.quantity':\"120"\,\n
      'Step 3.supply.vendor3.quantity':\"480"\,\n
      'Step 4.supply.vendor4.quantity':\"60"\,\n}"
```

I have to detect strings of type

```
'Step 2.supply.vendor2.quantity':\"120"\,\n.
```

I'm trying to use pattern and matcher of regex but I'm not able to figure out the correct regular expression for lines like

```
 <Beginning of Line><whitespace><whitespace><'Step><whitespace><Number><.><Any number & any type of characters><,\n><EOL>.
```

The `<Beginning of Line>` and `<EOL>` I have used for clarification purpose.

I have tried several patterns

```
String regex = "(\\n\\s{2})'Step\\s\\d.*,\n";
String regex = "\\s\\s'Step\\s\\d.*,\n";
```

I always get **IllegalStateException**: **No match found**.

I'm not able to find proper material to read on Java Regex with good examples. Any help would be really great. Thanks.

Comment: That looks like JSON format, are you sure you don't want to use a JSON parsing library?

Comment: This is JSON, you should use a JSON parser...

Comment: @JoseCifuentes Yes this is JSON format. I'm converting it into JSONObject after reading this data from file. And then fetching value for a particular key. But for fetching value for a key, I need to have my JSON data like this                                                                                                         'Step 2.supply.vendor2.quantity':"120",'Step 3.supply.vendor3.quantity':"480" ,i.e. without the \n and \" characters.

Comment: @DarthAndroid Can I still use JSON Parser for fetching a value for a key with those \n and \" characters.

Comment: I am confused a little. Is that string from your code or from some resource (file/socket/...)? If it is from your code then `\n` should be treated as one character representing line separator, not two characters ``\`` and `n` so in that parser should be able to handle it without problems. Did you try it? How did it go?

Comment: Do you mean to have `\"120"\,`, where the second `"` is not properly escaped?

Comment: @Pshemo These strings are from S3 file. I tried using the object mapper class after which I'm getting data in the conventional format: 'Step 2.supply.vendor2.quantity':"120",'Step 3.supply.vendor3.quantity':"480". Thanks a lot

Comment: @DarthAndroid The problem solved using Object mapper. Now my data is of the conventional JSON format, 'key':"value". Should I use regex java to match a particular key ? Or should I use a similar function of regex in JSON Parser ?

Comment: @user3263235 You iterate over the keys and match them however you want.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said in the comments, you should really use a JSON Parser.

But if you want to see how it could work with a regex, here is how you can do it :

- Take an example of a line you want to capture :`Step 1.supply.vendor1.quantity':"80"`
- Replace digits with `\\d*` (`\\d` matches any digit)
- Replace dots with `\\.` (dots need to be escaped)
- Add some parenthesis around the parts that you want to capture

Here is the resulting regex : `"Step (\\d*)\\.supply\\.vendor(\\d*)\\.quantity':\"(\\d*)\""`

Now, use a `Regex` and a `Matcher` :

```
String input = "{\n  'Step 1.supply.vendor1.quantity':\"80\"\\,\n";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Step (\\d*)\\.supply\\.vendor(\\d*)\\.quantity':\"(\\d*)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
  System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
}
```

Output :

```
1 //(corresponds to "Step (\\d*)")
1 //(corresponds to "vendor(\\d*)")
80 //(corresponds to "quantity':\"(\\d*)")
```

Comment: Which API can I use in JSON Parser library for the regex matching function ?